# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark') error when trying to extend MUI color palette

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, material-ui

Can't extend MUI color palette instead I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dark')`

This is my `theme.ts` file:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ff4400",
    },
    custom: {
      light: "#ffa726",
      main: "#f57c00",
      dark: "#ef6c00",
      contrastText: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
    },
});
export default theme;
```

This is `createPallete.d.ts` file:

```
import * as createPalette from "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Palette {
    custom: Palette["primary"];
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface PaletteOptions {
    custom?: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  }
}

// Update the Button's color prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    custom: true;
  }
}
```

Here is the use of custom color:

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export const LoginMobilePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <Button variant="contained" color="custom">
          test for bgc
        </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is the error which I'm getting when run with those configuration:

[image]

So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the throubleshoot, This problem was related to the fact that I had not used the themeProvider in top of my code

```
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ContentView>
        <App />
      </ContentView>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score -1):

The button no longer support the default color. These are the valid color values:

'inherit', 'primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'error', 'info', 'warning'
See the API page - https://mui.com/api/button/